How to find first image or video thumbnail in a webpage
How to find first image or first video thumbnail in a webpage? My code (below) retrieves an image but it's always not the first visible image and it doesn't fetch video thumbnails properly as well.
Sample URLs:

https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c0ve1zn9wlyo
https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c0r8edwj9wlo

The above are sample webpages, but I am looking for a generic logic that is able to get the first top image which covers an article.
Testing code:
How to make my code work more accurately?
public String fetchTopImage() throws Exception {
    // Select the top image element
    Element tImageElem = document.select("img").first();

    String tImage = null;
    if (tImageElem != null) {
        tImage = tImageElem.absUrl("src");
        log.trace("top image url is {}", tImage);
    }   
    else {
        log.trace("top image not found in {}", url);
    }   

    return tImage;
}


In your sample case,
This looks like made by Next.js with styled components.
Which means it might be inserting video or image dynamically by using Javascript code.
Possible Solution: 
Crawling is ALWAYS a specific fit as in your case, here you should fit your parser code to finding exactly what you want. Eg: video is not easy to parse because this video's thumbnail is inside an <iframe> which itself is inside another <iframe>.
I tested in Chrome with disabled Javascript, <video> doesn't show.
I think video is later inserted with Javascript after loading of page.
In this case, you can not parse video using JSoup.

Check if srcset exists and the first image found should be
camila cabello's image.

If you want first video, then use HtmlUnit or Selenium.


In case of second example, the code will parse gray.png, if you skip it, you should check if the srcset attribute exists or not, or else find other ways to parse the page properly.

In case of second example, It will parsed gray.png, if you skip it, you should check srcset attribute exists or not or other ways to parse properly. Crawling is ALWAYS fit as your case, you should fit your parser code fitting what exactly you want.
PS) video is not easy to parse it. because this video's thumbnail inside of iframe of iframe.

Additionally if you enable Javascript, the thumbnail of the video is hidden in 3 layers of shadow roots

Getting first img on the page seems not reliable way. On your second link, there is a big "Promo" block before the articles right now. So, it is unpredictable what will be first image in the layout when you script works.
It would be better to catch image needed using class and tags selectors. document.querySelector() will returns the first element within the document which match the selector, so we can use it.
On the second link (without video) every image is inside picture tag, so you can easily find first one with selector:
let a = document.querySelector("figure img").src;

On the first link we see the video container is a div with data-component="video-block". So we can distinguish it from others by this data-* attribute. Inside, some layers down, we see an img with class " holding_image". The class is found on Network tab of Inspector, just see all images downloaded. The selector for it will be:
let b = document.querySelector('[data-component="video-block"]');

Next, we can see there is not only one div with class "holdingImage": inside smp-video-layout, smp-preplay-layout and smp-error-layout. Only second one is visible, let’s find it:
let c = b.querySelector('smp-toucan-player');

The image we are looking for is hidden inside #shadow-root. Going deeper:
let d = c.shadowRoot;
let e = d.querySelector('smp-preplay-layout');
let f = e.shadowRoot;
let g = f. querySelector('.pre_play_layout_container');
let h = g.querySelector('smp-holding-image');
let i = h.shadowRoot;
let j = i. querySelector('.holding_image');
let k = j.src;

Here is it.
Sure, this chain can be written in one line, but it would be hard to read and to track what DOM nodes it finds.
The video preview is definitely downloaded and inserted after the page itself is loaded. So we need to find it not just after the page loaded, but after this block is updated. We already know how it should looks like, so next step is watch when the video block gets necessary content.
Or just wait some time to let the preview be downloaded. But this way is not reliable; it depends on Internet connection speed, possible connections issues and so on.


" I am looking for a generic logic that is able to get the first top image which covers an article."

Be aware that generic logic cannot work for all websites. Some websites create or load the data (image and video) dynamically when the code is running. The <image> tag might not exist in html source code, until some running JS function adds later such image into the page.
Possible Solution: 
For webpages with an <img> or <video> tag existing then generic logic can be done like this:
public String fetchTopImage() throws Exception {
    String tImage = null;

    // Search for <img> elements that have a 'src' attribute and are not empty
    Elements potentialImages = document.select("img[src]:not([src='']), img[data-src]:not([data-src=''])");

    // Search for <video> and <source> elements to find video thumbnails
    Elements videoElements = document.select("video, source");

    // Combine image and video elements for processing
    Elements allElements = new Elements();
    allElements.addAll(potentialImages);
    allElements.addAll(videoElements);

    // Check if any relevant elements were found
    if (!allElements.isEmpty()) {
        // Iterate over the combined list to find the first valid image or video thumbnail
        for (Element elem : allElements) {
            String imageUrl = elem.absUrl("src");
            if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                tImage = imageUrl; // Set the URL as the top image or thumbnail
                log.trace("Top image or video thumbnail URL is {}", tImage);
                return tImage; // Return the first valid URL found
            }
        }
    }

    log.trace("No top image or video thumbnail found in {}", url);
    return tImage; // Return null if no valid image or video thumbnail was found
}


public String fetchTopImage() throws Exception {
String tImage = null;


Element videoElem = document.select("video").first();
if (videoElem != null) {
    tImage = videoElem.absUrl("poster");
    if (tImage != null && !tImage.isEmpty()) {
        log.trace("Top video thumbnail is {}", tImage);
        return tImage;
    }
}

for (Element imgElem : document.select("img")) {
    if (imgElem.hasAttr("src") && imgElem.is(":visible")) {
        tImage = imgElem.absUrl("src");
        log.trace("Top visible image url is {}", tImage);
        break;
    }
}

if (tImage == null) {
    log.trace("No visible top image or video thumbnail found in {}", url);
}

return tImage;
}

Try this

I tried it and for the sample URLs mentioned above, it returned https://www.bbc.com/bbcx/grey-placeholder.png which is not correct. If you load the sample URLs you will know what I am looking for
